# Incrementing cells: a VBA logic algorithm

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to fill cells from A3 to A100 with numbers, as shown. Every three cells, the cell value increases of 1 digit. More than having the VBA snippet as an answer, which would be great, I would really appreciate if someone could be kind enough to make a step by step explanation of the logic behind building the code. I need to understand to racionalize on this in order to apply this knowledge in future and more complex endeavours.

A3 ---> 1

A4 ---> 1

A5 ---> 1

---

A6 ---> 2

A7 ---> 2

A8 ---> 2

---

A9 ---> 3

A10 --> 3

A11 --> 3

---

A12 --> 4

A13 --> 4

A14 --> 4

( . . . )

Comment: This is a **very broad** question, and it's actually not as much as question as a request for code. Although you've got some answers time time, the question has also been downvoted for the reasons above. Please consider working on this yourself in future and coming to us with a more specific question which we can reproduce easily and happily help you out with.

Comment: @CallundDA **(1)** Consistently, before recurring to this forum, I do my best rehearsing and experimenting. I was able to obtain a direct and satisfactory result myself, as similar as that of our friend "Storax". However, what I envisaged was to understand the reasoning behind building a code, to grasp the steps involved in creating something logic.

Comment: @CallundDA  **(2)** We ought to understand that, although questions may appear simple and straightfoward, not everybody has developed the same level of abilities or is as gifted as you may be. I thought that I could benefit from StackOverflow expertise, since browsing aleactory on internet did not yield me the didatic response I needed. I comprehend your concern and and I hope you take it as a positive feedback.

Comment: You’ve missed my point. No matter how much you’ve researched this yourself, if you don’t show us what you’ve done it looks to us like you haven’t done anything. There are *ways to ask questions*. Keep it specific and show us how far you’ve got with your problem in future :)

Comment: One more piece of advice if I may. I’m guessing, so I could be wrong, but it seemed like you only upvoted the answer which you accepted. Generally, you should upvote any answer which you found helpful. I usually wouldn’t say anything but since you commented on every answer saying it’s helpful I just thought mention that the correct mechanism for that is *upvoting*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manually, in **A3** enter:

```
=ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/3,0)
```

and copy down.

So with *VBA*:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Range("A3:A100").Formula = "=ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/3,0)"
End Sub
```

If you did not want formulas in the final result:

```
Sub poiuyt()
    With Range("A3:A100")
        .Formula = "=ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/3,0)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

**VBA approach via datafield array and flexible row settings**

Just to show another possible approach using a **datafield array** and allowing to define even ***individual start and end rows*** based on @CalumDa 's modified formula (assuming that you start always with *1, 1, 1* in the first three rows):

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub FlexibleRange()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet")  ' << change to your sheet name
Dim start As Long, last As Long, i As Long                        ' declare variables
start = 3: last = 100                                             ' << change to your individual rows
Dim v: ReDim v(start To last, 1 To 1)                             ' variant datafield array, counter
For i = start To last: v(i, 1) = Int((i - start) / 3) + 1: Next i ' calculate values
ws.Range("A" & start & ":A" & last) = v                           ' write numbers to column A
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Put in

```
A3 = 1
A4 = 1
A5 = 1
A6 = A3 + 1
A7 = A4 + 1
A8 = A5 + 1
```

Then copy A6 to A8 down to A100

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use VBA here? You can use the following formula on the worksheet. It doesn't depend on cells above so it'll give you the right answer whichever row you place it on:

```
=INT((ROW()-3)/3)+1
```

If you really want VBA there's not much to explain about this. It just places the same formula in the cells you require:

```
Public Sub FillColumnA()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:A100").Formula = "=INT((ROW()-3)/3)+1"
End Sub
```

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with this answer, downvoter please explain your reason for doing so...